# Angular/Bootstrap: Input fields and how to resize to content width on page load

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

and I have a series of input fields that resize their width based on the changes to their content using some inline JS and acts like an inline editor...

```
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg " value="{{project.pname}}" placeholder="Project Name" onkeyup="this.size = Math.max(this.value.length, 1)">
```

This works as expected however I am noticing that Input fields all seem to have a default width on page load regardless of any css styling (I have removed width 100% from the bootstrap css so css width is no factor in this. Seems an inbuilt default input width size from the browser settings.)

Anyway, this means when I have short strings I still have a wide input field and worse when I have long strings content is trimmed until i focus the item and press a key (even an up,down left or right will resize the box as expected.)

Is there any method to have these fields resize accordingly on page load.